# BOOST_FOREACH does not work inside template?

Tags: c++, templates, boost

I tried to use BOOST_FOREACH inside a template function with a custom, but type parameter independent iterator. I get 4-5 errors suggesting that my iterator class is not well defined as an iterator.

Rewriting the loop without BOOST_FOREACH, or "un-templatizing" the function makes the errors go away.

Is this a known limitation of BOOST_FOREACH?

### EDIT.

Sorry. Some code:

```
template <class T>
T fun()
{
    T result(0.0);

    BOOST_FOREACH(const math::IntegerVector &v, math::IntegerVectorRange(math::IntegerVector(2 , 2 ,2)))
    {
        // Do stuff.
    }

    return result;
}
```

The IntegerVector* types are well defined and work fine outside templates. Also they are NOT dependent on T.

The complete errors are:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/panayk/Workspace/petros-game'
Making all in src/c++
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/panayk/Workspace/petros-game/src/c++'
depbase=`echo fluid/Tracer.lo | sed 's|[^/]*$|.deps/&|;s|\.lo$||'`;\
    /bin/bash ../../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../..   -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include -O2 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -MT fluid/Tracer.lo -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo -c -o fluid/Tracer.lo fluid/Tracer.cc &&\
    mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Plo
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include -O2 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -MT fluid/Tracer.lo -MD -MP -MF fluid/.deps/Tracer.Tpo -c fluid/Tracer.cc  -fPIC -DPIC -o fluid/.libs/Tracer.o
In file included from /usr/include/boost/iterator/iterator_categories.hpp:15:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/iterator/detail/facade_iterator_category.hpp:7,
                 from /usr/include/boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp:14,
                 from ./math/Vector.h:5,
                 from ./fluid/Tracer.h:4,
                 from fluid/Tracer.cc:1:
/usr/include/boost/mpl/eval_if.hpp: In instantiation of 'boost::mpl::eval_if<mpl_::bool_<false>, boost::range_const_iterator<math::IntegerVectorRange>, boost::range_mutable_iterator<math::IntegerVectorRange> >':
/usr/include/boost/foreach.hpp:364:13:   instantiated from 'boost::foreach_detail_::foreach_iterator<math::IntegerVectorRange, mpl_::bool_<false> >'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/panayk/Workspace/petros-game/src/c++'
./fluid/InterpolatorGrid.h:45:3:   instantiated from here
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/panayk/Workspace/petros-game'
/usr/include/boost/mpl/eval_if.hpp:38:31: error: no type named 'type' in 'boost::mpl::eval_if<mpl_::bool_<false>, boost::range_const_iterator<math::IntegerVectorRange>, boost::range_mutable_iterator<math::IntegerVectorRange> >::f_ {aka struct boost::range_mutable_iterator<math::IntegerVectorRange>}'
In file included from fluid/Tracer.cc:3:0:
./fluid/InterpolatorGrid.h: In member function 'T fluid::InterpolatorGrid::interpolate(const std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<T> > >&, const RealVector&) const':
./fluid/InterpolatorGrid.h:45:3: error: no matching function for call to 'begin(const boost::foreach_detail_::auto_any_base&, boost::foreach_detail_::type2type<math::IntegerVectorRange, mpl_::bool_<false> >*, boost::enable_if_c<true, boost::mpl::and_<boost::mpl::not_<boost::foreach::is_noncopyable<math::IntegerVectorRange> >, boost::foreach::is_lightweight_proxy<math::IntegerVectorRange>, mpl_::bool_<true>, mpl_::bool_<true>, mpl_::bool_<true> > >::type*&)'
./fluid/InterpolatorGrid.h:45:3: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/boost/foreach.hpp:657:1: note: template<class T, class C> boost::foreach_detail_::auto_any<typename boost::foreach_detail_::foreach_iterator<T, C>::type> boost::foreach_detail_::begin(boost::foreach_detail_::auto_any_t, boost::foreach_detail_::type2type<T, C>*, mpl_::true_*)
/usr/include/boost/foreach.hpp:665:1: note: template<class T, class C> boost::foreach_detail_::auto_any<typename boost::foreach_detail_::foreach_iterator<T, C>::type> boost::foreach_detail_::begin(boost::foreach_detail_::auto_any_t, boost::foreach_detail_::type2type<T, C>*, mpl_::false_*)
/usr/include/boost/foreach.hpp:676:1: note: template<class T> boost::foreach_detail_::auto_any<typename boost::foreach_detail_::foreach_iterator<T, mpl_::bool_<true> >::type> boost::foreach_detail_::begin(boost::foreach_detail_::auto_any_t, boost::foreach_detail_::type2type<T, mpl_::bool_<true> >*, bool*)
/usr/include/boost/foreach.hpp:686:1: note: template<class T, class C> boost::foreach_detail_::auto_any<T*> boost::foreach_detail_::begin(boost::foreach_detail_::auto_any_t, boost::foreach_detail_::type2type<T*, C>*, mpl_::true_*)
./fluid/InterpolatorGrid.h:45:3: error: no matching function for call to 'end(const boost::foreach_detail_::auto_any_base&, boost::foreach_detail_::type2type<math::IntegerVectorRange, mpl_::bool_<false> >*, boost::enable_if_c<true, boost::mpl::and_<boost::mpl::not_<boost::foreach::is_noncopyable<math::IntegerVectorRange> >, boost::foreach::is_lightweight_proxy<math::IntegerVectorRange>, mpl_::bool_<true>, mpl_::bool_<true>, mpl_::bool_<true> > >::type*&)'
./fluid/InterpolatorGrid.h:45:3: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/boost/foreach.hpp:697:1: note: template<class T, class C> boost::foreach_detail_::auto_any<typename boost::foreach_detail_::foreach_iterator<T, C>::type> boost::foreach_detail_::end(boost::foreach_detail_::auto_any_t, boost::foreach_detail_::type2type<T, C>*, mpl_::true_*)
/usr/include/boost/foreach.hpp:705:1: note: template<class T, class C> boost::foreach_detail_::auto_any<typename boost::foreach_detail_::foreach_iterator<T, C>::type> boost::foreach_detail_::end(boost::foreach_detail_::auto_any_t, boost::foreach_detail_::type2type<T, C>*, mpl_::false_*)
/usr/include/boost/foreach.hpp:716:1: note: template<class T> boost::foreach_detail_::auto_any<typename boost::foreach_detail_::foreach_iterator<T, mpl_::bool_<true> >::type> boost::foreach_detail_::end(boost::foreach_detail_::auto_any_t, boost::foreach_detail_::type2type<T, mpl_::bool_<true> >*, bool*)
/usr/include/boost/foreach.hpp:726:1: note: template<class T, class C> boost::foreach_detail_::auto_any<int> boost::foreach_detail_::end(boost::foreach_detail_::auto_any_t, boost::foreach_detail_::type2type<T*, C>*, mpl_::true_*)
./fluid/InterpolatorGrid.h:45:3: error: no matching function for call to 'deref(const boost::foreach_detail_::auto_any_base&, boost::foreach_detail_::type2type<math::IntegerVectorRange, mpl_::bool_<false> >*)'
./fluid/InterpolatorGrid.h:45:3: note: candidate is:
/usr/include/boost/foreach.hpp:765:1: note: template<class T, class C> typename boost::foreach_detail_::foreach_reference::type boost::foreach_detail_::deref(boost::foreach_detail_::auto_any_t, boost::foreach_detail_::type2type<T, C>*)
make[2]: *** [fluid/Tracer.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Etc. This is too much for me to decipher, but IntegerVectorRange::begin() is there and returns a const_iterator. So is IntegerVectorRange::end().

### EDIT2 (IntegerVectorRange stuff)

```
class IntegerVectorIterator
: public boost::iterator_facade
<
    IntegerVectorIterator,
    const IntegerVector,
    boost::forward_traversal_tag
>
{
private:
    IntegerVector current;
    const IntegerVector start, limit;

    void increment();
    bool equal(const IntegerVectorIterator& other) const;
    const IntegerVector &dereference() const;

public:
    IntegerVectorIterator(const IntegerVector &start,
                          const IntegerVector &limit);
    IntegerVectorIterator(const IntegerVector &current,
                          const IntegerVector &start,
                          const IntegerVector &limit);

    friend class boost::iterator_core_access;
};

class IntegerVectorRange
{
private:
    const IntegerVector start, limit;
    const IntegerVectorIterator end_it;
public:
    IntegerVectorRange(IntegerVector limit);
    IntegerVectorRange(IntegerVector start, IntegerVector limit);

    typedef IntegerVectorIterator const_iterator;

    const_iterator begin() const;
    const const_iterator &end() const;
};
```

Comment: Please post example code that generates the error.

Comment: `IntegerVector` is qualified (`math::IntegerVector`) in one usage, and unqualified in a second usage.  Is that intended?

Comment: No it is not. Sorry. Corrected.

Comment: BTW, I see mutable iterator mentioned. Indeed this is not defined in my IntegerVectorRange class. IntegerVectorRange(IntegerVector(2,2,2)) represents the sequence (0,0,0), (0,0,1), (0,1,0), ... (1,1,1). It really does not make sense to try to modify this sequence. AND I have had no problems outside templates.

Comment: Wow. You shouldn't have gone to all this trouble. :-) I'll post the original definition. BTW, since the only answer was removed, and unless someone has a better explanation, you can make that into an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dummying up the missing classes, GCC doesn't like it: http://ideone.com/3O3OB. Clang++ compiles it just fine. So, I'd guess you've got a compiler bug, or maybe a bug in all the `#ifdefs` in `boost/foreach.hpp`

Particularly telling is this part of the instantiation backtrace:

```
eval_if<bool_<false>, range_const_iterator<...>, range_mutable_iterator<...> >
```

suggesting that whatever mechanism `BOOST_FOREACH` uses to determine if you're mutable iterating or const iterating has gotten the answer wrong this time.